# Blender 2.93 - Second Window always focuses

Tags: interface, customization, windows

I use dual monitors with Blender, and the newest update (2.93), doesn't let me keep other windows on top while blender is active. If I click on my primary Blender window, it moves the second window to the front as well, and it's not really ideal for when I'm looking at reference on the other window. Is there a way to turn this off? Where are the settings for it?

This wasn't an issue in Blender 2.92, since the the only window that would focus was the one you clicked on.

Comment: Look here: https://blenderartists.org/t/render-window-is-now-forced-to-be-on-top-of-main-window/1309100